# Single View One to many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two Models MainTransaction and SubTransaction

```
public class MainTrasaction{

 public int id{get;set;}
 public DateTime transDate{get;set;}
 public String transCode{get;set;}
 public String TransPoster{get;set;}
 public ICollection<SubTransaction>{get;set;}
}

public class SubTransaction{
public int id{get;set;}
public int MainTransId{get;set;}
public double debit{get;set;}
public double credit{get;set;}

}
```

I want to combine both of the Models in such a way, that in a Single Create Form, there will be one Row of MainTransaction and multiple Rows of SubTransaction. So i created a ViewModel

```
public class Voucher{
public MainTransaction mt{get;set;}
public List<SubTransaction> st {get;set}
```

}

The point of this ViewModel was to handle the creation of a Entry Form in which a single record of MainTransaction and Multiple Records of SubTransaction could be simultaneously inserted. However after having made the above viewmodel i am at loss to incorporate it in my view. Any suggestions folks. What should i do.

This is the controller Action

```
public ActionResult GenerateVoucher(){

return View();
}
```

And the View

```
@model VoucherProject.Models.Voucher

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.MainTransaction.transDate)
// And so on for all the MainTransaction fields
// SubTransaction.. Not sure who to proceed
/// Not sure what to do here..
```

Any ideas. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Apart from including domain models in your viewmodel I can see nothing wrong here.

Comment: How do i create 15 rows of SubTransaction so that upon submit they are bound to their respective model

Comment: "How do I..." questions aren't very well suited to SO's Q&A format. There are plenty of tutorials around the web that talk about MVC data binding. E.g. [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/), [here](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2012/09/17/modelbinding-with-complex-objects-in-asp-net-mvc/). You just need to build your view in a way that allows for dynamic addition/removal of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Are asking about the creation of the form, or the submission of the form data?
If I understand correctly, want to populate a View using a `Voucher` ViewModel. When you do that, you can iterate over the `SubTransaction` list in the View like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.st.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.st[i].debit)
}
```

Assuming you have populated the list with something, this will create inputs for every list item.  This is the form for user input.

When your data is POSTed to the controller method, the values will be bound to the 'Voucher' model and you can to do a `foreach` on the `List<SubTransaction>` and process them like this:

```
foreach (SubTransaction item in model.st)
{
    // process the SubTransaction record
}
```

Comment: But if i haven't populated the list, how do i then create the form, This form will be used to add new records, hence there will be no initial data.

Comment: To make it work this way, you would need to populate the model. You've used domain objects in your ViewModels which makes this awkward.

Comment: Any alternate approach.. Perhaps a Link